# "Table or view - fast load" option not shown in OLE DB Destination

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm using SSIS 2008 version. In the **OLE DB Destination** component, i can't find the option "Table or view - fast load".

Is there any setting that I have to enable to activate that option?

Thanks.

EDIT : I have created the mappings using the SSIS Import export wizard. Only those mappings does not have this Fast load option enabled. 
When I create a new mapping, the OLE DB destination has the Fast load option.

Comment: Oh no, not in the slightest. If anything, the reverse is true. Using the 'Table or View' option results in singleton inserts. For a thousand rows, there will be a corresponding thousands individual insert statements sent to the database and the log will have to accommodate those requests. No big deal, scale that up to 50+ million rows and watch your log explode. Or record # (50M -1) violates a constraint and you're left in an inconsistent state. For best performance, use fast load unless you have a reason to avoid it (concurrent access, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What provider are you using?
[image: Connection Manager properties]

You might be using a provider that does not support fast load?

Comment: Hi cairnz, I've selected the SQL Server Native client only when i chose the SSIS Import Export wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not confusing things?
The fast load option should appear only on the destination, not on the source (I know you said that but you may have got confused)

The only thing I found out is that apparently there is a bug accessing Netezza OLE DB destination:

```
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/569087/ssis-fast-load-option-missing-from-netezza-ole-db-destination
```

is that your case by any chance?

Comment: Hi Diego, i'm looking at the OLE DB Destination only and also I'm using SQL Server as the source and destination..I've added some more information to my post. Please check it. Thanks

Comment: try this: right click your destination component, choose "show advanced editor"  -> component properties. You should be able to set it there